# MySQL NULL value issue on SelectInt gorp

Tags: mysql, go, gorp

I'm trying to run the following query using gorp library with mysql

```
query = "SELECT SUM(outputoctets) FROM monthlyacct where date >= ? AND date < ? AND location = ?"
count, err := dbMap.SelectInt(query , constrains.From, constrains.To, constrains.LocationId)
```

This query throws the following error,

> Scan error on column index 0: converting string \"\u003cnil\u003e\" to
>   a int64: strconv.ParseInt: parsing \"\u003cnil\u003e\": invalid syntax

Here column outputoctets is type BIGINT. I also tried changing SelectInt to SelectStr, then it threw the following error;

> Scan error on column index 0: unsupported driver -\u003e Scan pair:
>   \u003cnil\u003e -\u003e *string

When I ran the query without location filter, it worked. Seems like this is due to some NULL values present in the location column. However I need to have the location filter on the query. How can I solve this?

Comment: What does MySQL output for the query?

Comment: It's always a number SUM(outputoctets)

Comment: SUM() returns NULL if there were no matching rows

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the additional location criteria is filtering out all results, so the sum(outputoctets) is null. `\u003cnil\u003e` is the string `"<nil>"`, which go rejects as an invalid integer.

Use a 'nullable' type to hold the sum, eg, [NullInt64](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#NullInt64)

Alternatively, use the mysql [IFNULL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) function to avoid returning a null from the query, eg, IFNULL(sum(outputoctets),0)

See the [Go database tutorial](http://go-database-sql.org/nulls.html) for more information